# Page Loading For PHP Web Application

Tags: php, mysql, load

About 3 days ago my application's page load became significantly slower, primarily during the period from clicking a hyperlink and the "Waiting for ..." notice loading.

It seems that once the "Waiting for ..." connects it speeds right up, but it stays in the "Waiting for..." loading state for anywhere between 15 to 25 seconds (average) depending on which page i am loading.

My question is - what is happening when the page is "Waiting for ..."? Is that my server, my application, a blank page that the app is trying to load but cannot find, or something else?

I have been running performance tests on my server, which is running fine. Separately, my website and 2 other applications run on the same server and are not experiencing any performance problems. Also have been monitoring "top" and my server cpu load is good (always under 15%). Also have been monitoring "mytop" for mysql performance and that is also good.

I am not sure what other tests I can run, or how to locate the issue.

Centos 6 dedicated server, database is mysql, application is written in php.

TO CLARIFY QUESTION:
If there is a clear answer that would be helpful - When you click a link on a page and the bottom left of the browser says "Waiting for yoursite.com..." and than after waiting is done it says "Connecting to yoursite.com..."

what is happening when the page is "Waiting for ..."?

Trying to narrow down my issue.

Comment: this question is way too vague for it to be answered here (specific questions will get specific answers), especially as the mere fact that you wrote it in php doesn't say anything about *how* you wrote it and in that all the possible causes for slowness... i can only recommend you to try and look for good tutorials on php based web apps or consider using a framework (if you're not doing it already)...

Comment: Edited question to hopefully be more direct in my question. I am not sure what else to test or how to go about testing (as i eliminated all options i can think of). The problem is def in the area of when the load is stuck on "Waiting for yoursite.com". Is there a better way to ask this question, looking for guidance as to what test to run next ( you can see tests already done in my original question ).

Answer (score 0):

Possible a memory leak on php, or some query that you use on your page load that may need some tunning... other issue could be dns conflict or dns redirecting.

Comment: think this is better fit for a comment as the question is not very exact, so your answer is also not more than a series of guesses...

Comment: Yes of course, silly of me to write this on an answer and not on the comment. Yes just trying to inquery more detail on the problem. Thanks for the heads up.